# Why are some contacts in Zoho Invoice greyed out?

Tags: zoho

In the new Zoho Invoice, there are contacts (instead of customers). For some reason, some of my contacts' names are grey, instead of black.

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greyed-out contacts are inactive contacts.

**Mark As InActive** can be done only by the user.

In Zoho Invoice, You can manage your contact. If you would like to keep the contact in Zoho Invoice but you don't like to record any transaction to the particular contact then we have the option called "Mark As Inactive".

Once you make the contact as inactive then invoice creation page will not shown the contact to record transaction. But in contact list, it will keep shown to you for access the contact info like phone number. You can also make the customer active any time by clicking the Mark As Active option.

Comment: Could you add a brief explanation to your answer of what makes a contact "inactive"?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal I have updated my answer for better understanding